# Limitation of number of pods per node on aks

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-aks

can we set the maximum of pods per node smaller than 30?

We would like to use a /27 subnet which means there are only 30 usable IPs.

Right now we get the following error message:

> Pre-allocated IPs 31 exceeds IPs available in Subnet 27

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `maxPods` property of your cluster when deploying an AKS cluster from an ARM template. You'll do this inside the `agentPoolProfile` section of your cluster. Here's an example snippet:

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/subid1/resourcegroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/clustername1",
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/ManagedClusters"
  "location": "eastus",
  "name": "mycluster1",
  "properties": {
    "agentPoolProfiles": [
      {
        "count": 3,
        "dnsPrefix": "agentpool1dnsPrefix",
        "fqdn": "agentpool1fqdn",
        "name": "agentpool1",
        "osType": "Linux",
        "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks",
        "vmSize": "Standard_D2_v2",
        "maxPods": 25
      }
    ],
    // cut for brevity
}
```

As of 2018-05-30, the [PR for the updated OpenAPI spec](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/pull/3131/files#diff-f375c83cdb498c90611abad7566ca641R831) hasn't been merged yet, but you can find the relevant fields there

There's also a full sample template that includes `maxPods` at [github.com/Azure/AKS/examples/vnet/02-aks-custom-vnet.json](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/blob/99865a7bcb2cc614ed70d7ce3598b2b5bdf4d254/examples/vnet/02-aks-custom-vnet.json)